# A metric space (X,d) in which any intersection of open sets is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Assume we have a metric space (X,d) that satisfies the condition that the intersection of any collection of open sets is open. Explain which subsets of (X,d) are open?

Comment: All of them....

Comment: Why? I am trying to show it, but I get stuck

Comment: "All of them" is actually a big hint. Bigger hint: Show that a subset containing just one point is open.

Comment: Hint : What is $\bigcap_{x\in U}U$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in X$, $n>0$ an integer, $\cap_nB(x,1/n)=\{x\}$ is open, thus every singleton is open and henceforth, every subset of $X$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

All sets are open! To see this note that for each $x\in X$, the set $\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\{y\in X|d(x,y)<\frac{1}{n}\}=\{x\}$ is open. Hence, for any set $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ is open. Note that we only need that countable intersections of open sets be open.